# Como integrar o android com o visual studio 2013?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013

Olá pessoal gostaria de saber se é possível integrar o `Android` no `Visual Studio 2013`

Comment: É possível, porém quer desenvolver em qual linguagem? Se for em `Java`  creio que não seja possível, somente `Cordova html+java script`, `C# (Xamarin)`.

Comment: Entendi, achei que programava em java também.

Comment: O melhor é usar o Android Studio é muito bom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo objetivamente sua pergunta: **Sim**. É possível desenvolver para `Android` usando o Visual Studio.

Para desenvolver seus apps, você tem duas opções:

- [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/visual-studio) (usando a linguagem C#).
- [Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx) (usando html + javascript)

---

Mas, seu comentário sugere que você gostaria de desenvolver em Java usando o Visual Studio. Nesse caso, a resposta já muda. Hoje **não** é possível desenvolver em java usando o Visual Studio.